# count calculated field in query access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have a query where I want to calculate the open position - close (count the closed rows in another table) and to exclude all the 0 results

```
SELECT Positions.[Req #], tblPositionList.PositionName, 
       Positions.[Opening Date], Positions.[Close Date], 
       Positions.Status, Count([OpenPosition]![Close Date]) AS Closed,
       Positions.Openings AS Opened, [Opened]-[Closed] AS Remaining
FROM tblPositionList INNER JOIN (
       Positions INNER JOIN OpenPosition ON Positions.[Req #] = OpenPosition.[Req #]) 
ON (tblPositionList.PositionID = Positions.PositionID) AND
   (tblPositionList.PositionID = OpenPosition.PositionID)
GROUP BY Positions.[Req #], tblPositionList.PositionName, Positions.[Opening Date], 
         Positions.[Close Date], Positions.Status, Positions.Openings;
```

I want to add a filter to Remaining field.

Comment: Try to replace `!` by `.` in `Count([OpenPosition]![Close Date])`

Comment: Hi Sergey, 
Thank you. The code is working as it is but I want to add a filter on Remaining

Comment: You cannot calculate a field in a `SELECT` list and use the name of that field later in the same `SELECT` list. Instead of `[Opened]-[Closed] AS Remaining` try using `Positions.Openings - Count([OpenPosition]![Close Date]) AS Remaining`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @user3728595, it works perfectly.
The final script is

```
 SELECT Positions.[Req #], tblPositionList.PositionName, Positions.[Opening 
    Date], Positions.[Close Date], Positions.Status, Count([OpenPosition]![Close 
    Date]) AS Closed, Positions.Openings AS Opened, Positions.Openings-
    Count([OpenPosition]![Close Date]) AS Remaining
    FROM tblPositionList INNER JOIN (Positions INNER JOIN OpenPosition ON 
    Positions.[Req #] = OpenPosition.[Req #]) ON (tblPositionList.PositionID = 
    Positions.PositionID) AND (tblPositionList.PositionID = 
    OpenPosition.PositionID)
    GROUP BY Positions.[Req #], tblPositionList.PositionName, Positions.[Opening 
    Date], Positions.[Close Date], Positions.Status, Positions.Openings
    HAVING (((Positions.Openings-Count([OpenPosition]![Close Date]))>0));
```